Better way to create column containing sequential values
I have the following dataframe:
df = pd.DataFrame({'sku' : ['A','A','A','A', 'B', 'B', 'C','C','C'],
                  'price': [10,10,10,10, 8,8,9,9,9]})

out:
    sku price
0   A   10
1   A   10
2   A   10
3   A   10
4   B   8
5   B   8
6   C   9
7   C   9
8   C   9

My issu
I want to create a new column (named t) containing sequential values according to column sku in order to get the following output:
 sku    price   t
0   A   10  1
1   A   10  2
2   A   10  3
3   A   10  4
4   B   8   1
5   B   8   2
6   C   9   1
7   C   9   2
8   C   9   3

My current code:
t = [1]
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    if df['sku'][i-1] != df['sku'][i]:
        t.append(1)
    else:
        t.append(t[i-1] + 1)

df['t'] = t

Is there a better way to do it?

df['t'] = df.groupby('sku').cumcount().add(1)
